# Replace items inside a list in a column in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, regex, pandas

Suppose I have a pandas df:

```
import pandas as pd
ex = pd.DataFrame({'Title': ['Data Scientist', 'Data Analyst', 'Data Engineer'], 
                   'Skills': [['Python', 'R ', 'C ', 'C++'], ['Python', 'R,', 'C ', 'C++'], ['Python', 'R ', 'C,', 'C++']]})
```

If I want to replace `R[space]` and `R,` with `R` and `C[space]` and `C,` with `C`, how should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `strip`

```
ex.Skills=[[y.strip() for y in x] for x in ex.Skills]
ex
Out[755]: 
            Title               Skills
0  Data Scientist  [Python, R, C, C++]
1    Data Analyst  [Python, R, C, C++]
2   Data Engineer  [Python, R, C, C++]
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! What if I have a comma in the string after `C` or `R` (something like this `C,` or `R,`)? (Just modified my example df for the question?)

Comment: @katie `[[y.replace(',','').strip() for y in x] for x in ex.Skills]`